# How to make Google Chrome JavaScript console persistent using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How to make Google Chrome console persistent?
In Network tab their is a option "preserve logs" how to set this using selenium webdrver.

In case of firefox their is preference "devtools.webconsole.persistlog" If "devtools.webconsole.persistlog" is set to true then it will enable persistent logging(preserve logs). any equivalent preference/way in Chrome.?

Comment: DesiredCapabilities did not help ?

Comment: Nope. It did not help. I guess preference is firefox is different from chrome.

Comment: Check this out - may be this should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726192/enable-preserve-log-in-chrome-programmatically-using-chromedriver